# What else do people who have realized Nirvāṇa do besides teach?

Tags: nirvana, lay-buddhism

> There are numerous references in Buddhist literature to men and women living ordinary, normal family lives who successfully practised what the Buddha taught, and realized Nirvāṇa.

--[What the Buddha Taught](https://books.google.com/books?id=tw7wBxzPL4cC&pg=PT107&dq=normal%20family%20lives%20who%20successfully%20realized%20Nirv%C4%81%E1%B9%87a&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw_-vZgffYAhVi74MKHQueDkUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=normal%20family%20lives%20who%20successfully%20realized%20Nirv%C4%81%E1%B9%87a&f=false).

What else do people who have realized Nirvāṇa do besides become teachers? Can you cite examples?

Comment: They lay back and chill.

Comment: Some get cooking classes.

Comment: I wanted to say something funny, but it would be completely inappropriate and out of character ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do what is right.

If they have family to support, they support the family. If they need money to survive, they work. If they are hungry, they eat. If they need a car, they drive a car. etc.

Comment: Apparently lay arahants have to become monks immediately after enlightenment according to Milindapanha. If that's the case, they can't support their families or work. See [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/20924/471) and [this forum discussion](https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=9645).

Comment: @beginner I won't need examples. Your answer make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

those who realized Nirvana can do any good thing but they don't produce any result example , suppose an Arahant gives alms , he does not get 'kusal' or merits he has only actions which don't give any positive or negative results.