# What is Destruction of Lay arahathood?

Tags: theravada

when lay person attains enlightment he has to die that same day within 24 hours or else become monk if not there is destruction of life what is the future of such person ?

Comment: You possible might find an answer to your question, Pranay, within this similar topic: [answer on "Must Lay Arahants become Buddhist Monks?"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/24673/12996) *[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, given for release, not meant for commercial use or other lower wordily gains by ways of exchange or trade.]*

Answer (score 0):

They leave the laylife within 7 days, not 24 hours. This is why Pacceka Buddhas go to live in the forest since there is no Sangha community.